# Estimate for $\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\sum_{b=1}^{p-1}\frac{b}{a(ab)_p}$, where $p$ is a large prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, asymptotics

Is this estimate true? Can anyone give a proof of it?

$$
\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\sum_{b=1}^{p-1}\frac{b}{a(ab)_p}=\frac{1}{2}p\ln^2 p+o(p\ln^2 p)\qquad (p\text{ prime, } p\to\infty)
$$
where $
(ab)_p\equiv ab\;(\operatorname{mod}p)$, $0<(ab)_p<p$.

Comment: For what range of $p$ have you calculated it?

Comment: p is a large enough prime number@ Gerry Myerson

Comment: Would it be anyhow useful to rewrite the LHS as a sum over $n=ab$?

Comment: This would give something like $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{(p-1)^2}\sum_{d\mid n,d\leq\sqrt{n}}\dfrac{d^2}{n(n)_{p}}}$.

Comment: Which should be $\leq(1+o(1)\dfrac{1}{p-1}\sum_{n=1}^{(p-1)^2}\tau(n)$.

Comment: What you write in note as "we have" is exactly what you ask about. So, I am confused: do you have it or not?

Comment: Where does such a sum arise?

Comment: Tricky sum. It is known that the residues $(ab)_p$ are equidistributed in $\{1,\dotsc,p-1\}$ when the pair $(a,b)$ ranges in a discrete rectangle $A\times B$ of size at least $p^{3/2+\epsilon}$. See, for example, http://www.nieuwarchief.nl/serie5/pdf/naw5-2000-01-4-380.pdf However, it seems nontrivial to deduce from here the OP's conjecture. I also rewrote the OP's sum in terms of Kloosterman sums, and the main term exhibited the expected asymptotics, but I failed to show that the error term is negligible. Anyways, these are the natural ideas to explore first (in my opinion).

Comment: It is plausible that the equidistribution statement mentioned in my previous remark holds for $|A\times B|>p^{1+\epsilon}$. If this is the case, then the OP's conjecture can be deduced in a straightforward way, by localizing $a$ in short intervals and $b$ in long intervals.

Comment: @GH from MO: would the result you conjecture follow from (G)RH?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: I don't know. I think my conjecture is folklore, but its connection to GRH is unclear. My conjecture has more to do with the distribution of Kloosterman sums.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer but a simple heuristic argument: if you set $r=(ab)_p$, the OP's
sum is equal to
$$\sum_{1\le r\le p-1}\dfrac{1}{r}\sum_{1\le a\le p-1}\dfrac{1}{a}(ra^{-1})_p$$
This proves immediately that the sum is less than $(p-1)H_{p-1}^2$, asymptotically $p\log(p)^2$, and if we assume (heuristic part) that $(ra^{-1})_p$ has average
$(p-1)/2$ we indeed obtain a guess of $p\log(p)^2/2$. Maybe this last part can be made rigorous.

EDIT: if you consider the much simpler SINGLE sum $S(p)=\sum_{1\le a\le p-1}\dfrac{(a^{-1})_p}{a}$, the same heuristic would give an asymptotic of $p\log(p)/2$. However, numerically $S(p)/(p\log(p))$ does NOT seem to tend to a limit, but oscillates between something like $0.38$ and $0.52$. This should be much easier to analyze, and perhaps indicate that there is also some oscillation in the OP's original question, with no limit.

Comment: In the limit of large $p$, could we approximate the OP's double sum by a double integral on some square to support your heuristic argument?

Comment: The single sum over $a$ is harder to analyze (in my opinion) than the double sum over $a$ and $r$. In general, extra averaging helps not only the outcome, but also the analysis.

Comment: To my eye, the numerical data for the single sum is quite consistent with the theory that $S(p) = \frac12p\log p + X(p) p$, where the $X(p)$ defined by that equation looks like a fixed bump-shaped random distribution.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but an argument that your sum is between $(1/4+o(1))p\log^2(p)$ and $(3/4+o(1))p\log^2(p)$.

Write $S(p)$ for your sum. Separate the sum into pieces according to the integer part of $(ab/p)$:
$$
\begin{align*}
S(p)&=\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{a}\sum_{k=0}^{a-1} \sum_{kp/a<b<(k+1)p/a} \frac{b}{ab-kp}\\
&\sim\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{a}\sum_{k=0}^{a-1} \frac{kp}{a}\sum_{kp/a<b<(k+1)p/a} \frac{1}{ab-kp}.\\
\end{align*}
$$
The innermost sum is the sum of reciprocals of integers in an arithmetic progression. The first term in the progression is $(-pk)_a$, and the sum of the reciprocals of the other terms in the progression is $\log(p/a)/a+O(1/a)$, so
$$
\begin{align*}
S(p)&\sim\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{a}\sum_{k=0}^{a-1} \frac{kp}{a}\left[\frac{1}{(-pk)_a}+\frac{1}{a}\log\left(\frac{p}{a}\right)\right]\\
&=p\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{a^3}\log(p/a)\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}k+p\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{a^2}\sum_{k=1}^{a-1}\frac{k}{(-pk)_a}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}p\log^2(p)+p\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{a^2}\sum_{k=1}^{a-1}\frac{k}{(-pk)_a}.
\end{align*}
$$
This gives the claimed lower bound for $S(p)$. For the upper bound, we observe that for fixed $a$, we have $\{(-pk)_a:1\leq k\leq a-1\}=
\{1,\ldots,a-1\}$. So an upper bound for the second term above is
$$
p\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{a^2}\sum_{k=1}^{a-1}\frac{k}{a-k}\sim \frac{1}{2}p\log^2(p).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but here is the plot for the first 200 primes:

[image]

Maple code:

```
with(plots):
f := proc(p) 
 option remember;
 return evalf(add(add(b/a/modp(a*b,p),b=1..p-1),a=1..p-1)/p/ln(p)^2);
end:
listplot([seq(f(ithprime(k)),k=10..200)],style=point);
```

(Obviously this is completely unintelligent, and much more efficient methods are doubtless possible.)

Comment: Just to be clear, this isn't the sum, it's the sum divided by $p(\log p)^2$.

Answer (score -1):

I feel obliged to flesh out my comments (and to modify my wrong answer, thanks to GH from MO).

Write $n=ab$, and let $H_{k}$ the $k$-th harmonic number, $\tau(n)$ the number of positive divisors of $n$. LHS is greater than the related sum $\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\sum_{b=1}^{a}\dfrac{b}{a(ab)_{p}}$, that we'll denote by $S$.

Provided the limit as $\tau(n)$ tends to $\infty$ of $f(n):=\frac{2}{\tau(n)}\sum_{d\mid n,d\leqslant\sqrt{n}}\dfrac{d^{2}}{n}$ exists and equals a positive constant $M$, we have:

$S=\sum_{n=1}^{(p-1)^2}\sum_{d\mid n,d\leqslant\sqrt{n}}\dfrac{d^2}{n(n)_{p}}\sim\sum_{n=1}^{(p-1)^2}\sum_{d\mid n,d\leqslant\sqrt{n}}\dfrac{M}{(n)_{p}}\sim\sum_{n=1}^{(p-1)^2}\sum_{d\mid n,d\leqslant\sqrt{n}}M\dfrac{H_{p-1}}{p-1}\sim M\sum_{n=1}^{(p-1)^2}\sum_{d\mid n,d\leqslant\sqrt{n}}\dfrac{\log(p-1)}{p-1}$.

The idea is to consider all divisors of $n$ less than its square root, and to replace $\dfrac{1}{n_p}$ by its average value, which is $\dfrac{H_{p-1}}{p-1}\sim\dfrac{\log(p-1)}{p-1}$ (in my comment I erroneously took the reciprocal of the average value and not the average value of the reciprocals, hence the missing $\log(p-1)$).

We thus obtain $S\sim M\dfrac{\log(p-1)}{p-1}\sum_{n=1}^{(p-1)^2}\dfrac{\tau(n)}{2}$. As $D(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{x}\tau(n)$ is provably asymptotic to $x(\log x+K)$ where $K$ is a positive constant (see Dirichlet divisor problem on Wikipedia), we end up with:

$S\sim\frac{M}{2}\frac{\log(p-1)}{p-1}(p-1)^2(\log (p-1)^2+K)\sim Mp\log^{2} p$ which provides a lower bound for the sum of the OP of the desired order of magnitude.

Edit: the following link: http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?5,1967230,1967504#msg-1967504 shows that if $M$ exists, it equals $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Can you get a lower bound this way, too?

Comment: Your first display only covers the pairs $(a,b)$ satisfying $b\leq a$ (since your $d^2/n$ equals $b/a$).

Comment: So a multiplicative factor equal $2$ is needed?

Comment: No, a different argument is needed. Your first display talks about a very different sum than the original post.

Comment: It would be the same if the sum over $b$ went from $1$ to $a$, right?

Comment: Yes, obviously. Anyways, I don't want to chat about this, but you need to be careful.